# ParseFloat function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, floating-point, parsefloat

When I am adding two textbox values that are **1.001** and **0.001** and then I do a `parseFloat` I get **1.0019999999**. I want it **1.002** . Can you help me?

Answer (score 27):

The Javascript [Number](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_number.asp) class has a `toFixed()` function that will get you what you want.

So you could do `parseFloat("1.0019999").toFixed(3)` and that would give you **1.002**.

The parameter (3 in this case) is the number of digits to show after the decimal point

Comment: Thank you, 17 of 26. I didn't know about the toFixed() function.

Comment: The toFixed() method returns a string(instead of number) representation of a number in fixed-point notation. So we should be careful while dealing with toFixed() method.

Answer (score 10):

0.002 cannot be accurately represented as a base 2 number. Similar to the way that 1/3 can't be represented in base 10.

1/3 = 0.33333... recuring. To represent the number accurately in base 10, you would need an infinite number of decimal digits.

0.002 is a number that can be accurately represented in base 10 (as we see here), but not in base 2, as used by computers. To represent this number accurately, would take an infinite number of binary digits.

Comment: Nice theoretical work that contributes nothing to answer the question.

Answer (score 6):

This is a known problem: see [accuraty problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Accuracy_problems)
and the minimisation of the accuracy problem: [minimisation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Minimizing_the_effect_of_accuracy_problems)

Answer (score 6):

The javascript methods `Number.toFixed()` and `Number.toPrecision()` can help here, but [they return a `String`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toPrecision). A possible solution is as follows:

```
var x = parseFloat(parseFloat("1.0019999999").toPrecision(3));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to a quick fix you can round to the nearest thousandth

Math.round((1.001+0.001)*1000)/1000

Comment: I voted that one down, because JS now has helper methods for such tasks and readable code is important.