# JavaScript parseFloat error: 1.445 + 2 = 3.4450000000000003

Tags: javascript, html, parsefloat

I encountered this weird anomaly creating a simple javaScript demo that I am going to use to teach my 11 year old the basics of coding. I think that perhaps I didn't sanitize the input strings before I used the javaScript parse float javaScript function. The program works fine for other floating point decimals ie. 2.5 + 3 = 5.5. However in this one instance 1.445 + 2 = 3.4450000000000003. Purely out of curiosity I would like to know what is going on here. So with out any further delay, here's the JavaScript code:

```
var funct = null;
function clarifyOperation(x)
{
    if(x=="add")
    {
        document.getElementById("operation").innerHTML="&nbsp;&#43;&nbsp;";
        funct="add";
    }
    else if(x=="subtract")
    {
        document.getElementById("operation").innerHTML="&nbsp;&#45;&nbsp;";
        funct="subtract";
    }
    else if(x=="multiply")
    {
        document.getElementById("operation").innerHTML="&nbsp;&#215;&nbsp;";
        funct="multiply";
    }
    else if(x=="divide")
    {        
        document.getElementById("operation").innerHTML="&nbsp;&#247;&nbsp;";
        funct="divide";
    }
}

function solve()
{
    var x=document.getElementById("inputX").value;
    var y=document.getElementById("inputY").value;
    var z;
    if(funct=="add")
    {
        z=parseFloat(x)+parseFloat(y);
        document.getElementById("result").value=z;
    }
    else if(funct=="subtract")
    {
        z=parseFloat(x)-parseFloat(y);
        document.getElementById("result").value=z;
    }
    else if(funct=="multiply")
    {
        z=parseFloat(x)*parseFloat(y);
        document.getElementById("result").value=z;
    }
    else if(funct=="divide")
    {
        z=parseFloat(x)/parseFloat(y);
        document.getElementById("result").value=z;
    }
}
```

Here is the HTML code:

```
<input type="text" value="" id="inputX"/>
<span id="operation">&nbsp;</span>
<input id="inputY" type="text" value="" />
<span>&nbsp;&#61;&nbsp;</span>
<input type="text" value="" id="result" /><br />
<input type="radio" name="operation" value="add" onchange="clarifyOperation(this.value)" />
<span>&#43;</span><br />
<input type="radio" name="operation" value="subtract" onchange="clarifyOperation(this.value)" />
<span>&#45;</span><br />
<input type="radio" name="operation" value="multiply" onchange="clarifyOperation(this.value)" />
<span>&#215;</span><br />
<input type="radio" name="operation" value="divide" onchange="clarifyOperation(this.value)" />
<span>&#247;</span><br />
<input type="button" value="calculate" onclick="solve()" />
<hr />
```

Reminder to the community: keep your comment's useful.

Comment: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is JavaScript's Floating-Point Math Broken?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-javascripts-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: Note to the OP: the fundamental question you're asking isn't too bad (the problem is well-understood, but it's difficult to search for if you don't know the phrase "floating point"); however, your question is probably getting so many downvotes because your example code is needlessly long. You can recreate the problem using only a few lines of code.

Comment: Also, if you are going to teach programming then you should encourage the use of meaningful variable names.

Answer (score 1):

There are some fair explanations done in these SO answers that describes the problem with decimal numbers in computers, with Javascript in mind.

- [Parse float function in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/173884/parsefloat-function-in-javascript?rq=1)
- [Is Javascript's floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-javascripts-floating-point-math-broken)

To fix the numbers to not have wonky decimals though you may round them with `toFixed(…)` function. Such as this:

```
(parseFloat('1.445') * parseFloat('2')).toFixed(3);
```

Comment: Worth noting that `toFixed` returns a string.